# Issue with creating a new object with a form (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite, web-deployment

I am using the Django framework to build a website.  This website is user based and each user has a profile model.  Right now, I am working on building a system where each user can input their job experience.  I want it so that you can input a category, and then fill out points for each category.  (For example, if you wrote for the New York Times, the category would be "New York Times" and then right under it would be the articles you wrote in bullet points).  I am at the stage where I am simply trying to make it so that the user can create a new category.  I have an edit profile page where the user can already edit some details from the models.  I tried to add on a form that creates a new category.  When you submit the category, a success message dispays but when I look at my admin panel it doesn't create the object under categories.  Here is the code:  (Note: this form lets you choose the user for the category, I have to change it later to make it so that the category gets set to the user thats currently logged in)

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 


from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Social, Category
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, FormView

from .forms import(
     UserRegisterForm,
     UserUpdateForm,
     ProfileUpdateForm,
     BiographyForm,
     AccessCodeForm,
     AddCategory,
 )
from django.apps import apps
Post = apps.get_model('blog', 'Post')

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                  request.FILES, 
                                  instance=request.user.profile)
        b_form = BiographyForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        c_form = AddCategory(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid() and b_form.is_valid and c_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            b_form.save()
            c_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('editprofile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        b_form = BiographyForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        c_form = AddCategory(instance=request.user)
    
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'b_form': b_form,
        'c_form': c_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/editprofile.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Work(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='') 
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

editprofile.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img style= "float:left" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">&nbsp;&emsp;{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
          {{ u_form|crispy }}
          {{ p_form|crispy }}
          {{ b_form|crispy }}  
          {{ c_form|crispy }}     
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" action="Edit">Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile, Social, Category, Work

class AddCategory(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'date', 'user']
```

The code above did not work and it did not create a new category.  However,  I tried a **different** method and it can successfully create a new category.  I created a new page and a new view to show just a singular category form.  This form also sets the user to the user logged in.

views.py (second  method):

```
class CreateCategory(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Category
    fields = ['name', 'date']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('editprofile')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateCategory, self).form_valid(form)
```

category_form.html(second method):

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<h1> Category Form </h1>

<div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

This second method successfully results in the creation of a category and I can see it on the admin page.  I would prefer to have the category creation on the editprofile.html with all the other forms.  I am not sure why the first method is not working.  I believe it has something to do with my views.py and how the model is set up.  If I could somehow integrate the second method into the editprofile.html, that would work great as well.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your AddCategory form also? And did you debug and check whether `u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid() and b_form.is_valid and c_form.is_valid()` evaluates to `True`?

Comment: @Kholdarbekov  I forgot to add my forms.py to the question, thank you for catching that.  I edited the question and will try the debug.

Answer (score 0):

According yo your AddCategory form its model is Category. So when you pass instance parameter it must be instance of the Category model, but you are sending request.user

I think it should be something similar to: (In this case you are sending last category assigned to user)

```
c_form = AddCategory(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.category_set.last())
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe that this is the main problem like you said.  I tried instance=request.user.category but that got a an Atribute Error ('User' object has no attribute 'category').  I have tried to set a related_name but I have not yet succesfully passed the instance parameter.

Comment: Yes that error is due to Category model has ForeignKey to User. That's ManyToOne relation (One user can have Many Categories). In your case you need to pick one of the categories. You can do smth like: `request.user.category_set.last()`. I have updated my answer, pls refer to it